# IE7 img -  a href, looking for work-around

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-7

I have this issue occurring, its an annoying bug in IE7.

[image]

The a `href` around the `img` claims a newline on the left right above 'Boston Whaler'.

I don't manage to find a workaround for this. Maybe some of you do?

```
img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:block;
}
```

I reproduced the problem over here: http://bouwknecht.nl/ie7bug

Comment: Can you give url to the site? The problem can't be the href.

Comment: Can you post your source on jsfiddle.com or a similar site? by the look of your DOM and CSS I think the <a> tag is causing the problem, since you are floating an element inside of it, <a> tags dont have display block, and it isn't really floating, the margins on the element inside of it expand outside of the containing element in this case the <a> tag, all this from what I can observe and deduct from your screenshot, so I might be just wrong

Comment: @ram4nd: it says in the image, http://bouwknecht.nl/boten

Comment: I reproduced the problem over here: http://bouwknecht.nl/ie7bug

Comment: Your website doesn't have a DOCTYPE declaration, so it's displayed in quirks more. And different browsers have different quirks. So can you try with a DOCTYPE?

Comment: @MrLister There you go http://bouwknecht.nl/ie7bug

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong with your CSS rules found here - [bouwknecht.nl/boten](http://bouwknecht.nl/boten) - inside your list elements <li> you have floating content ( the <img> tag ) which shouldn't be floating, I assume means you want to float your image to the left, you need to float the <a> tag parent of the <img> and give it the same margins as inside the <img> needless to say remove any styling from that <img> tag, also the div.price has a big bottom margin, is there a reason for this? you need to let the <li> element know you have floating elements inside and that the height needs to be recalculated maybe a clearfix type of solution works here, meanwhile overflow: hidden; works on the <li> element but going back to your div.price you will need to fix the margins since you are working with negatives, I tried fixing this with margin: 0; and it worked just fine, this might not be the "Answer for IE7" but once you fix your rules you will make sure every browser does it's best to conform to the spec, if you write bad code then browsers try to be smart and fix it for you using each its unique way thus working in some

Comment: Haha, thanks for your affords! .price has nothing to do with this.

I simplified the code, and placed it over here. I don't see why floating isn't allowed inside a <li>.
http://bouwknecht.nl/ie7bug/

Comment: @cobra91 Agreed. Why shouldn't you be able to float things inside an `<li>`? The margins may play a role though; could you try giving the h3's a margin of 0?

Comment: @rroche Although you're right about the `boten` site, the much simpler `ie7bug` site also has the problem, which clearly points to a difference in IE vs other browsers rather than errors.

Comment: you can float inside a <li> you just need to be careful with the height of the element

Comment: @cobra91 on your example link you just posted, a better solution will be to always wrap the img with a div and float that div instead of the img and a tags

Answer (score 0):

In IE7, if you also apply `float:left` to the h3 element, it will align to the top. In that case, make sure that you apply `clear:both` to each li element.

Comment: With some extra containers (div's) I could manage to get it working in IE7... I wouldn't be pleased to do so. ;)
If I have to...